# Epimorphism (abelian group)

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-groups, abstract-algebra

Let $(G,\cdot), (H,*)$ Groups and $f: G\rightarrow H$ an Epimorphism. Show that: If G is an abelian group, then H is also an abelian group. Is the reversal of this proposition also true?

My idea: 
Let $x,y \in f(G)$ $\Rightarrow x=f(\alpha) $ and $y=f(\beta) $ for special $\alpha, \beta \in G$

(1) $x*y=f(\alpha)*f( \beta) = f(\alpha \cdot \beta)$ (Group homomorphism)

(2) $y*x = f( \beta)*f(\alpha)=  f(\beta \cdot \alpha) = f(\alpha \cdot \beta)$ because G is abelian

$\Rightarrow x*y=y*x \Rightarrow H$ is abelian group, and because it's surjectiv it's  true for all $x,y \in H$

Comment: Yes your proof is correct. As for the converse, can you construct an epimorphism from $S_3\times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, for instance?

Comment: your proof  is correct!

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I have no idea, could you help me to do that?

Comment: Or even easier, an epimorphism from $S_3$ to $C_2$.

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft Can you give me a hint please?

Comment: Actually, the easiest counterexample to the converse is the unique surjection from a nonabelian group to the trivial group, which is abelian. So take any nonabelian group and send everything to the identity in the trivial group.